# RSS feed <link rel="alternate"> on which pages?

Tags: rss, feeds

I've got a site that includes a blog amongst other things. I'm adding the  tag for autodiscovery of the RSS feed.

There's only one feed on the site. Should  live on every page (i.e. I put it in the base template)?

Or should it just live on the blog index page and/or individual blog post pages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put it on every page. Your goal is to get people to subscribe to your feed and you want to take advantage of every opportunity to get them to do so. Since all that tag does (in the major browsers) is put the RSS icon in the address bar it's hardly intrusive. So put it in the `<head>` of every page and maximize the chances of someone subscribing.

Comment: On the other hand, if you someone seems it on the "about us" page, might they think that they are subscribing to that page if it changes?

Comment: @Paul They shouldn't as browsers should tell them what the subscription is for when they click on it.